# ng-grid first line rendered only, and cannot catch selection event

Tags: ag-grid

I'm working on my own project using angurarjs and ag-grid.
I have 2 problems:
1. is that i cannot refresh a status bar in case of selection in ag-rig. I can catch the event, and the function is running, but statusText scope element is reresshed only after navigation is happend to an other page. Very strange behaviour.
2. only the first 3 lines of grid is rendered, and only after scrolling the rest is shown.
Could anyone help me?

Code:

```
$scope[page + 'GridOptions'] = {
    columnDefs: [],
    rowData: null,
    onGridReady: $scope.fillGrid,
    rowSelection: 'single',
    onSelectionChanged: function(){
        $scope.selectRow()
    }
}

$scope.selectRow = function(){
    localStorageService.set(page + 'SelectedRow', $scope[page + 'GridOptions'].api.getSelectedRows()[0])
    console.log($scope[page + 'GridOptions'].api.getSelectedRows()[0])
    $scope.statusText = "selected item's id: " + $scope[page + 'GridOptions'].api.getSelectedRows()[0]._id
    for(i=0; i<$scope[page + 'GridColumns'].length; i++){
        localStorageService.set($scope[page + 'GridColumns'][i].field, $scope[page + 'SelectedRow'][$scope[page + 'GridColumns'][i].field])
        $scope[$scope[page + 'GridColumns'][i].field] = localStorageService.get($scope[page + 'GridColumns'][i].field)
    }
    console.log(page)
    localStorageService.set(page + 'DisableButton', false)
    $scope[page + 'DisableButton'] = eval(localStorageService.get(page + 'DisableButton'))
    $scope[page + 'GridOptions'].api.refreshView()
}
```

Comment: Are you using angular to compile the rows?

Comment: Yes. Meanwhile the first issue is solved, but the second is still alive. The containing div is having fix height in px. If i change it to 100%, every row is rendered, but i dont want my page to be scolled.

Comment: Then you have a problem in your css. Maybe if you share the html/css involved I can help you.

Comment: I'm using Jade templating, but i can describe it. It has only one class, which is the ag-fresh, and a style of 100%. My grid is in a bootstrap container, which has a height of 500px, Nothing else is there in the css. That is why i'm confused.

Comment: Weird, it should be working. I'll try to reproduce your problem in  a fresh environment, though it looks like I might not be able to